# Конвертировать список кортежей в словарь списков

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Коллеги, есть вопрос по оптимизации. Дан список кортежей, например:

```
a = [(1,5,6), (7,8,9), (10,12,4)]
```

Сразу оговорюсь, что в реале кортежей миллионы и в каждом кортеже семь элементов, а данный пример, это только пример, для простоты восприятия.

Надо преобразовать этот список кортежей в словарь списков, таким образом чтобы все нулевые элементы кортежей стали одним списком, первые элементы - следующим списком, третьи - следующим... Ключи будут заданы вручную.
Вот так:

```
a_d = {'key1':[1,7,10], 'key2':[5,8,12], 'key3':[6,9,4]}
```

Я знаю как решить эту задачу с помощью `Pandas`. Как-то так:

```
import pandas as pd
a = [(1,5,6), (7,8,9), (10,12,4)]
a_d = {key: list(val) for key, val in dict(pd.DataFrame(a, columns=['key1', 'key2', 'key3'])).items()}
```

Вопросов два:

1. Есть ли способ решить эту задачу с помощью базового Питона и стандартных библиотек без перебора всех элементов. Может есть какой-то стандартный метод/функция, который я упускаю.
2. Будет ли этот способ быстрее чем описанный выше способ через `Pandas`?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
keys=['key1', 'key2', 'key3']
a = [(1,5,6), (7,8,9), (10,12,4)]

dct = dict(zip(keys, map(list, zip(*a ))))
print (dct)
```

Результат:

```
{'key1': [1, 7, 10], 'key2': [5, 8, 12], 'key3': [6, 9, 4]}
```

Ответ про "быстрее" легко получить самостоятельно замерив время выполнения кода. Но советую для этого брать массив побольше, на трех или 9 элементов вы разницы можете и не получить, не знаю, не пробовал.

P.S. Кстати, обратите внимание, что в исходном списки у вас кортежи, а в результате вы хотите получить значения-списки. Это лишнее преобразование. Если вас устроят значения-кортежи, то оператор еще более сократиться до:

```
dct_tuples = dict(zip(keys, zip(*a )))
```

P.P.S. Благодаря замечания уважаемого Stanislav Volodarskiy в комментариях  коды еще более сокращены. Думаю и по времени выполнения тоже.

Comment: Не удивлюсь если это способ будет в десять раз быстрее чем "Pandas".

Comment: Да спасибо, исправил.

Comment: Спасибо, исправлено, авторство улучшений - отмечено !

Comment: Спасибо автору ответа и @StanislavVolodarskiy! Замеры произвел, докладываю. Во-первых, у меня получилось, что во-втором случае (без использования `map`) в значениях все равно получаются списки, а не кортежи, либо я что-то не то делаю, либо способ с `map` излишен и не имеет смысла.  По замерам: был взят список из более чем 800 000 кортежей. Каждый кортеж состоит из семи элементов среди которых `int, float, str`...

Comment: Разобрался почему у меня получались списки, без map действительно получаются кортежи.

Comment: Измерял время выполнения трех различных методов конвертации: 1. С помощью `Pandas` как указано в самом вопросе. 2. С помощью `dict(zip(keys, map(list, zip(*a ))))` конвертация в словарь списков 3. С помощью  `dict(zip(keys, zip(*a )))` конвертация в словарь кортежей. Как сказано выше, тестовый список состоял из >800 000 кортежей по 7 элементов. Каждый метод я запускал 100 раз и получал среднее время итерации. Итог. 1. Через `Pandas`: **1.0497 сек.**; 2. С помощью `map(list,)` в словарь списков: **0.9181 сек.**; 3. В словарь кортежей: **0.5136 сек.**. Ответ получен, спасибо!